# Linux/CUPS printing example/tutorial?

Tags: c++, c, linux, printing, cups

I need to print some vector data (or to be more exact: some dots and polylines) using Linux. When I ask Google for that it shows me many tutorials and documentations - but all for end users, no programming examples.

So does anybody know a good programmers HOWTO/tutorial that shows printing under Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CUPS doesn't have its own document description API. It doesn't need one: formats like PostScript, PDF, and JPEG are first-class citizens of CUPS. You use whatever program or API you like to create a such a file, and you then send it to CUPS (with `lpr` or with the CUPS API) and CUPS will transform it to the appropriate internal format and send it to the printer.

So, for your case, you might use a vector graphics library like [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/manual/) to author PostScript, and then you send that off to CUPS for printing. Here's a simple C example:

```
// compile with:
//   gcc -Wall -o cairo_print cairo_print.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo` `cups-config --cflags --libs`

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-ps.h>
#include <cups/cups.h>

// A4 width, height in points, from GhostView manual:
//   http://www.gnu.org/software/gv/manual/html_node/Paper-Keywords-and-paper-size-in-points.html
#define WIDTH  595  
#define HEIGHT 842  

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc!= 2){
    fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s word\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  // setup
  char* tmpfilename = tempnam(NULL,NULL);
  cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_ps_surface_create(tmpfilename, 
                                                     WIDTH, 
                                                     HEIGHT);
  cairo_t *context = cairo_create(surface);

  // draw some text
  cairo_select_font_face(context, 
                         "Arial Black", 
                         CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, 
                         CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
  cairo_set_font_size(context, 30);
  cairo_move_to(context, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
  cairo_show_text(context, argv[1]); // the text we got as a parameter

  // draw a dotted box
  const double pattern[] = {15.0, 10.0};
  cairo_set_dash(context, pattern, 2, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(context, 5);
  cairo_rectangle(context, WIDTH*0.33, HEIGHT*0.33, WIDTH*0.5, WIDTH*0.5);
  cairo_stroke(context);

  // finish up
  cairo_show_page(context);
  cairo_destroy(context);
  cairo_surface_flush(surface);
  cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

  // print
  cupsPrintFile(cupsGetDefault(), tmpfilename, "cairo PS", 0, NULL);
  unlink(tmpfilename);

  return 0;
}
```

Strictly you don't need that temporary file: the CUPS API allows you to construct a stream and you can emit the page data into that (but a file is handy for debugging).

Comment: I have been trying to printing surface data directly to cups rather temp file with proper DPI. Could you suggest which api? Thanks

Comment: Dinesh Kumar Govinda: that would require using the CUPS API to find a printer, open a job on it, and then stream the data into the corresponding job. That's quite a different topic to this question. I'd recommend that you create a new question (tagged [cups] and [c]) to ask it, as you'll attract more attention than asking there. If I remember how (it's been a few year) I'll answer there, but maybe someone more experienced with CUPS with help you there.