# Best approach to access printer under Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to find the best approach to send data to print (Thermal and HP laser A4) connected to my Ubuntu system.

I can access printer by writing in `/dev/usb/lp*`. What is the best approach to do it using c++ as programming language.

Thanks,

Comment: Accessing the device directly is always a bad idea, you should use some configuration value that let you control the sending to a printer spooling system (lpr/lp).

Answer (score 4):

As Ubuntu and a lot of other Linux distros use CUPS as printing system, I would recommend that your app only communicates with CUPS. Like that you can avoid having to implement printer specific stuff, but you have a generic way that should work on any Linux distro supporting cups.

See here for a handy example for printing using cups: [Linux/CUPS printing example/tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518004/linux-cups-printing-example-tutorial)

Comment: CUPS [official documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-overview.html) for reference. (Looking that link up first allowed you to ninja the answer. ;-) )

Comment: What i have done using CUPS is taking a simple example from CUPS documentation and try to send RAW data to thermal printer, but printer don't recognize CUPS job.